# parse_known_args not thowing exception for empty input

Tags: python

The following function is behaving differently for 2 different calls.

First time , _argv is empty and its throwing exception

Second time, _argv is empty but its not throwing exception

The function run_command is being called in try block.

```
def run_command(cmd, cmd_parser, sub_argv):
    print ('Entering run_command')
    _argv = sub_argv
    index = -1
    values_specs = []
    if '--' in sub_argv:
        index = sub_argv.index('--')
        _argv = sub_argv[:index]
        values_specs = sub_argv[index:]
    print ('argv is ')
    print (_argv)
    try:
        known_args, _values_specs = cmd_parser.parse_known_args(_argv)
    except Exception as err:
        print('excpetion is')
        print(err)
    print ('known args')
    print (known_args)
    cmd.values_specs = (index == -1 and _values_specs or values_specs)
    print ('Exiting run_command')
    return cmd.run(known_args)
```

First time when i run i get the correct exception getting thrown by parse_known_arguments . Hence program is showing help menu .

```
get parser full name:%s tacker vnf-create
DEBUG: tackerclient.tacker.v1_0.vm.vnf.CreateVNF Entering CreateCommand::get_parser
DEBUG: tackerclient.tacker.v1_0.vm.vnf.CreateVNF Entering TackerCommand::get_parser
DEBUG: tackerclient.tacker.v1_0.vm.vnf.CreateVNF Exiting TackerCommand::get_parser
Entering CreateVNF::add_known_arguments
Exiting CreateVNF::add_known_arguments
DEBUG: tackerclient.tacker.v1_0.vm.vnf.CreateVNF Exiting CreateCommand::get_parser
Exiting 1 run_subcommand
Entering run_command
before if condition
before parsing args
argv is
usage: tacker vnf-create [-h] [-f {html,json,shell,table,value,yaml}]
                         [-c COLUMN] [--max-width <integer>] [--prefix PREFIX]
                         [--request-format {json,xml}] [--tenant-id TENANT_ID]
                         [--name NAME] --vnfd-id VNFD_ID
                         [--config-file CONFIG_FILE] [--config CONFIG]
tacker vnf-create: error: argument --vnfd-id is required
```

But when i run for different input the parse_known_args line is not throwing any exception eventhough argv is empty .

```
Entering run_command
before if condition
before parsing args
argv is
known args
Namespace(columns=[], description=None, formatter='table', max_width=0, name=None, prefix='', request_format='json', tenant_id=None, variables=[], vnfd=None, vnfd_file=None)
value specs
[]
Exiting run_command
```

please help !!!

Comment: In the first run I don't see an exception. Looks more like `cmd_parser.parse_known_args()` ends the whole program after printing the help text. Is the `cmd_parse` object the same in both calls? Could it be every `cmd` has its own set of options and therefore its own parser instance and you are calling with another (sub)command in the second example. One that has no mandatory options, hence an empty `sub_argv` is okay‽